# Posting Date to Asp.net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using asp.net core web API 2.1. I'm sending request with postman. I'm sending "10.12.2019". But, I'm getting "12.10.2019" from my controller.cs. How can I fix this error?

**MyController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod([FromBody]MyClass myClass)
{
}

public class MyClass {
    public DateTime myDate { get; set; }
}
```

**my request**

```
http://localhost:5012/api/MyController/MyMethod
```

**my json**

```
{
  "myDate": "10.12.2019"
}
```

**My startup.cs**

```
  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("tr-TR");
           options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("tr-TR") };
       });
```

Comment: Try sending in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: Post culture agnostic date value

Comment: I want solve from c# @Farshan. I don't want change JSON object that I send.

Comment: I don't understand @VidmantasBlazevicius. Can you explain?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir You need to either send a valid date format or read as string and parse yourself

Comment: Why MM/dd/yyyy is valid.But why dd/MM//yyyy is not valid? @Franck

Comment: By default, the body consider the date in the default culture of your host. So either you have set your culture or provide the global format.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir dd/mm/yyyy is a valid format but dd.mm.yyyy is not. It doesn't know how to parse it. You can change your system default date format so your application know how to parse. It should work.

Comment: I send  "10/12/2019". But again I took "12/10/2019" @Franck

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Your computer is set MM/DD/YYYY in your control panel, regional settings. DateTime object takes their format from the regional settings the computer currently uses. change the WINDOWS settings of date to DD/MM/YYYY and it will see "10/12/2019" as "10/12/2019". Your windows setting are currently MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: I want always using dd/MM/yyyy. So, I wrote my startup.cs something in my question. But, it isn't change anything. Should I write something else? Can you check my edited question? @Franck

Comment: @HasanOzdemir I cannot answer for .NetCore but with standard .Net you change your culture by code with this line  `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Localization working perfectly in .Net. But in .net core,  I can't achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the culture your service uses then you can set it in `Startup.cs` and add it inside the `Configure()` method.

This works for me (add it before `app.UseMVC()`):

```
var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
});
```

The above will displays a date correctly in dd.MM.yyyy format when calling `.ToShortDateString()`. However, when POSTing a date it wouldn't bind/parse correctly.

To correctly parse a date format when POSTing you need to set the culture of the JSON serializer.  We can set the culture of the JSON serializer in  `AddJsonOptions()`.

Add this to the `ConfigureServices` method and it should solve the issue.

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR"); 
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Haldo. I did all of your said. When I test by `.ToShortDateString()` , it is 'dd.MM.yyyy' format. Working perfectly. But, when I send POST request by postman, it is 'MM.dd.yyyy' again @Haldo

Comment: Have you added both `app.UseRequestLocalization()` and `.AddJsonOptions()` with `dd.MM.yyyy` format? That works for me. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Make sure the date format in `AddJsonOptions()` is *exactly* `dd.MM.yyyy`. It fails if it's `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir If you could send the date in `yyyy.MM.dd` (or ISO8601) format that would be the least ambiguous format and will probably resolve the problem.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir I've updated my answer. Try adding `options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("TR-tr");` to `AddJsonOptions`

Comment: `options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");` worked. Thanks a lot @Haldo.

Answer (score 4):

Try this JsonConvert attribute for custom date

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public MyDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
}
```

And use the attribute for your property as

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

this will automatically convert the body to the expected format.

if you are expecting all datetime properties in this format then add this global settings in your `startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc()  
   .AddJsonOptions(options =>  
   {  
     options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString= "dd-MM-yyyy";  
   });
```

But you have to make sure all the values given for that property should be in the provided format. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Can I do by changing my localization @Farshan ?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir i guess it will work. if you using `app.UseRequestLocalization("tr-TR");` with supported cultures in your configure method in startup.

Comment: Thanks again @Farshan . When I test by `.ToShortDateString()` , it is 'dd.MM.yyyy' format. Working perfectly. But, when I send POST request by postman, it is 'MM.dd.yyyy'

Comment: `options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");` is fixed my problem from answer of Haldo's answer. Thanks for your helps @Farshan.